# simple html dom - find within a find

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I need some help with simple_html_dom.

I am trying to parse a data table with many table rows.  Inside some of the td cells there is some further div tags that I need to parse separate.

```
    foreach($html->find('tr.statistics') as $data) {
    $cell_one = $data->find('td', 0)->plaintext;
    $cell_two = $data->find('td', 1)->plaintext;
    $cell_three = $data->find('td', 2)->innertext
    }
```

this works as it should, but i further need to find two div tags in $cell_three.

$cell_three data looks like this

```
<div id="_Div_Line85">65</div><div id="_Div_Line95">56</div>
```

So my question is, how would I go about getting the contents within those two div tags?

Comment: So you need to strip out the HTML and only have `65` and `56`?

Comment: that is correct, i am trying to get both numbers into there own variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use chaining.

```
$sub_1 = $data->find('td', 2)->find('td',1)->plaintext;
$sub_2 = $data->find('td', 2)->find('td',2)->plaintext;
```

Comment: thanks, but i have tried something similar to this and I am not able to get it to work.  when i remove the ->innertext from $cell_three it just hangs and times out.   $cell_three = $data->find('td', 2)->innertext; at least give me the two divs inside the td cells. but i need to parse those div tags

Comment: how about chaining?
$sub_1 = $data->find('td', 2)->find('td',1)->plaintext;

Comment: thank you so much!  $data->find('td', 6)->find('div',1)->plaintext; was the answer I needed!

Comment: Great. I'll edit my answer above to reflect that. Please mark it as Accepted so it helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will convert each `div` into an array and then strip the HTML code.

```
$cell_three = $data->find('td', 2)->innertext;
$cell_three = explode("</div>", $cell_three);
$cell_three = array_map(function($v){
    return trim(strip_tags($v));
}, $cell_three);
```

Then you just loop over the array.

```
foreach($cell_three as $sub_cell){
    $sub_cell_one = $sub_cell->find('td', 1)->plaintext;
    $sub_cell_two = $sub_cell->find('td', 2)->plaintext;
}
```